# Replace of self join in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, self-join

I have a scenario on following tables:

**SampleData**: (has one hour periodic values of a Prod.)

```
TST_DATE            CLK_LITRE_WT    
---------------------------------
09/15/2019 17:15    1280            <-- current time value
09/15/2019 16:15    1300            
09/15/2019 15:15    1190            
09/15/2019 14:15    1200            
09/15/2019 13:15    1200
```

`CLK_LITRE_WT` is prod name out of 13 products. So totally 14 columns are there. But it doesn't matter. Note that no of row/hour is given user.

**SettingMaster**:

```
UserCode    LastRunDate
------------------------------------
aa          2019-09-15 15:18:01.350
```

`LastRunDate` is nothing but Last DB reached time of a User. So I need query which should be like and **Expected Result**:

```
TST_DATE            CLK_LITRE_WT_Real   CLK_LITRE_WT_Seen   
-----------------------------------------------------------
09/15/2019 17:15    1280                1190            <-- value of previous live record. 
09/15/2019 16:15    1300                1190            <-- value of previous live record. 
09/15/2019 15:15    1190                1190            <-- Last seen record by User.
09/15/2019 14:15    1200                1200            
09/15/2019 13:15    1200                1200
```

I tried `Self Join`, `LEAD-LAG` (will share the query soon). But I did not achieve the expected result. So I need your help for how can I get the Expected result.

**Edit 1:**

I recreate `LEAD-LAG` what I tried yesterday.

```
select TST_DATE, CLK_LITRE_WT CLK_LITRE_WT_Real, lead (CLK_LITRE_WT) over (order by convert(datetime,sd.TST_DATE + ':15.00') desc) CLK_LITRE_WT_Seen 
from SettingMaster sm left join SampleData sd 
on convert(datetime,sd.TST_DATE + ':15.00') between dateadd (hour, -(4), '2019-09-15 17:20:02.733') and '2019-09-15 17:20:02.733' 
where sm.UserCode = 'aa' 
order by convert(datetime,sd.TST_DATE + ':15.00') desc
```

Here yesterday date and time was passed static. Because, given data are yesterday data. And result is:

```
TST_DATE            CLK_LITRE_WT_Real   CLK_LITRE_WT_Seen
09/15/2019 17:15    1280                1300
09/15/2019 16:15    1300                1190                <-- value of previous live record
09/15/2019 15:15    1190                1200                <-- here should be '1190' as Real
09/15/2019 14:15    1200                NULL
```

Comment: `will share the query soon` ... actually you should share the query _now_, without which your question isn't really complete.

Comment: my files are closed unexpectedly. so i need to rewrite that. At the same time, if i share my request, i will get some solution..!!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have added my question. and mention the reason of tried query missing.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization

Comment: @philipxy I could not understand what you trying to say...!!

Comment: I am summarizing what the link says, read it & act on it.

Comment: Yes, I read that link. That's too confusing me..